# Push notifications implemented in worklight are not received in an Android device when the device is closed

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, google-cloud-messaging

Push notifications implemented in Worklight are not received by an Android device when the device is powered-off. When I power-on the device, the push notification which was sent when the device was powered-off is never received in the notification bar.

CASE OF FAILURE TEST STEPS (push notification send when device is powered-off):

1. Power-off the device
2. Send push notification to the device while it is powered-off
3. Power-on the device
4. This LogCat shows so the push notification seems to be arriving to the device. However the push notification never shows in the notification bar, neither in the application

LogCat:

```
05-14 14:39:12.180: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4829): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
05-14 14:39:12.180: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(4829): GCM IntentService class: com.ibm.cio.be.android.navas.SmarterParking.GCMIntentService
05-14 14:39:12.180: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4829): Acquiring wakelock
05-14 14:39:12.210: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4829): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
05-14 14:39:12.230: W/com.worklight.common.Logger(4829): com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed once.
05-14 14:39:12.230: D/GCMIntentService(4829): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:101 :: WLGCMIntentService: Received a message from the GCM server
05-14 14:39:12.230: W/GCMIntentService(4829): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:108 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.
05-14 14:39:12.250: D/GCMIntentService(4829): GCMIntentService.addToIntentQueue in GCMIntentService.java:123 :: WLGCMIntentService: App is not on foreground. Queue the intent for later re-sending when app is back on foreground.
05-14 14:39:12.250: V/GCMBaseIntentService(4829): Releasing wakelock
```

5. In the server side (websphere), the logs shows this message every two minutes:

   ```
    [5/14/15 8:36:26:581 EDT] 000002de BinaryDownloa E   FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
    com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: FWLSE3034E: The application "ParkUP" was not found in project "ParkingApp".
   ```

The device seems to be receiving the push notification from the server but the notification does not show on the notification bar.

CASE OF SUCCESS CASE (Push notification send when device is powered-on and app on background):

1. Set the application on background
2. Send push notification to device
3. Push notification appears perfectly on notification bar. This logCat shows.

LogCat:

```
05-14 15:05:54.540: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9805): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
05-14 15:05:54.540: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9805): GCM IntentService class: com.ibm.cio.be.android.navas.SmarterParking.GCMIntentService
05-14 15:05:54.550: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9805): Acquiring wakelock
05-14 15:05:54.570: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9805): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
05-14 15:05:54.580: W/com.worklight.common.Logger(9805): com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed once.
05-14 15:05:54.580: D/GCMIntentService(9805): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:101 :: WLGCMIntentService: Received a message from the GCM server
05-14 15:05:54.580: W/GCMIntentService(9805): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:108 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.
05-14 15:05:54.600: D/dalvikvm(1043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3909K, 27% free 16903K/23012K, paused 26ms+13ms, total 212ms
05-14 15:05:54.600: D/GCMIntentService(9805): GCMIntentService.addToIntentQueue in GCMIntentService.java:123 :: WLGCMIntentService: App is not on foreground. Queue the intent for later re-sending when app is back on foreground.
05-14 15:05:54.600: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9805): Releasing wakelock
05-14 15:05:54.610: D/GCMIntentService(9805): GCMIntentService.onUnhandled in GCMIntentService.java:164 :: WLGCMIntentService: Showing notification for unhandled Message(alert=Sorry, your booking for tomorrow has been cancelled by the slot owner! Try again to book another slot. Good Luck!, badge=1, sound=null, payload={"alias":"myPush","custom":"data"})
05-14 15:05:54.620: W/ResourceType(1157): CREATING STRING CACHE OF 44 bytes
```

In this case, the LogCat is exactly the same as the failure case except for the GCMIntentService.onUnhandled being called.

Also I will like to add that if I test sending the push notification when the device has not access to internet, and then I give access to the internet to the device it works fine too.

I've tested for the provided sample in worklight tutorial and the same issue is happening, however in this case I'm not testing with the websphere server, I'm testing with the local worklight server, so I don't see the server logs do not apply to this case.

Has anybody faced this issue and found a solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Closed as in locked or closed as in powered off?

Comment: what do you mean by closed or screen locked.

Comment: Is the `time_to_live` option specified when the messages are sent to GCM server?

Comment: Hi, it fails when closed as in powered off. When the screen locked it works fine.

Comment: Specific Worklight version and build number?

Comment: Wl 6.2.0.01. What do you mean with build number?

Comment: the numbers that come after 6.2.0.01... look in Eclipse > About > Worklight

Comment: WL 6.2.0.01-2014127-1531

Comment: If I send the push notification when the mobile disconnected from the internet, the push notification is received when the internet connection is started. I'm wondering what is the difference between this case and when sending the push notification when the mobile is powered off. In both cases the server log is the same: "com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: FWLSE3034E: The application "..." was not found in project "..."". However, in the "power-off" case, this exception keeps showing every 2mins after it is available again.

Comment: Just tried the scenario for power off with 6.2 and V7... The device received the message after it switched on and connected to the network... It took a minute to receive the notification. Can you update the question with the logs you see?

Comment: LogCat logs and messages.log

Comment: I've included the logCats and the problem seems to be that it is missing the call to : GCMIntentService.onUnhandled in GCMIntentService.java:164 :: WLGCMIntentService: Showing notification for unhandled Message(alert=Sorry, your booking for tomorrow has been cancelled by the slot owner! Try again to book another slot. Good Luck!, badge=1, sound=null, payload={"alias":"myPush","custom":"data"})

Comment: We've tested in the pushnotification sample provided in the "Getting started" tutorial of worklight, and we are facing the same issue. When the application is powered off and then powered on, the push notification does not show in the notification bar

Comment: @IreneMarquet, per Neeraj's answer - edit the question to provide step-by-step reproduction as for us it is working.

Comment: We've done some testing with different devices and we've found that this issue is highly dependent on the device type. In some devices the test case is successful but in others it isn't. ¿Is there any known fix for this problem? or a reason for what this is happening? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an Answer as the comment has character limit... This is not a complete answer to the question you are having

- When the application is on the foreground the notification bar won't show the message as it will be consumed by the application. Otherwise the message goes to the notification bar.
- When the device is powered off or it is not in the network, the message is delivered when the device connects to the network. Its delivered to the notification bar if the application is not in the foreground.

The term "application is powered off" as I understand means that the application is closed or it is not running even in the background... Right?

From the tests I did with the sample, I see that the notification does get delivered to the notification bar. Also I don't see the "FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found" with the push notification sample. To be able to help you better, can you please describe the steps you followed to hit this issue with the Push Notification sample.

Comment: In my post, the second logCat relates to the app when it was on background and the device is open (I've edited as I wrote it incorrectly). The The term "application is powered off" means that the device is powered off. I'm going to edit the question now to reproduce the steps I took to make it clear. The "FWLSE3002E" i see it in the server side when I test my application, not the sample one. I'm using a websphere sever. However with the sample app I see the enclosed logCats for both situations. ¿Could it be a proble specific of the device I'm testing?

Comment: I have to add that I've tested with another Android device and it works fine. The devices were the failure occurs are Sony Xperia M2 Android 4.4.2. The device were I've tested and goes ok is HTC Android 4.4.1. I've tested already in several devices Sony Xperia M2 Android 4.4.2 and the push notification fail. Do you know what might be causing the issue, the devices receive perfectly push notifications from other applications.

Comment: I again tested this on Android 5 and works fine ... I do see onUnhandled getting invoked in the logcat. Let me confirm... Are you saying that this issue only occurs on Sony Xperia M2 Android 4.4.2?

Comment: The defect also occurs in HTC mini Android 4.4.2. In the other devices we've tested the scenario works.